# Using glm in R for linear regression on a large dataframe - issues with column subsetting

Tags: r, linear-regression, genetics

I am trying to use glm in R using a dataframe containing ~ 1000 columns, where I want to select a specific independent variable and run as a loop for each of the 1000 columns representing the dependent variables.

As a test, the glm equation works perfectly fine when I specify a single column using `df$col1` for both my dependent and independent variables.

I can't seem to correctly subset a range of columns (below) and I keep getting this error, no matter how many ways I try to format the df:

```
'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
```

What I tried:

```
df = my df
cols <- df[, 20:1112]

for (i in cols{
    glm <- glm(df$col1 ~ ., data=df, family=gaussian)
}
```

Comment: you need to do `glm(y~x, data = data.frame(y = df[,i], x = df[, "specific_column"], family = gaussian)`

Comment: There is a reasonably large number of questions on this very topic (running a linear or GLM with lots of different predictor variables, or lots of different responses, or all combinations of predictors and responses ...) but I don't have a good search strategy for finding them ATM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more idiomatic to do:

```r
predvars <- names(df)[20:1112]
glm_list <- list()  ## presumably you want to save the results??
for (pv in predvars) {
    glm_list[[pv]] <- glm(reformulate(pv, response = "col1"), 
       data=df, family=gaussian)
}
```

In fact, if you really just want to do a Gaussian GLM then it will be slightly faster to use

```r
lm(reformulate(pv, response = "col1"), data = df)
```

in the loop instead.

If you want to get fancy:

```r
formlist <- lapply(predvars, reformulate, response = "col1")
lm_list <- lapply(formlist, lm, data = df)
names(lm_list) <- predvars
```